# What's the Equivalent of ALT+F4 in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

And how to set it up as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>? (With the intended effect of closing windows)

PS: the "another question" asks for the purpose of it and doesn't address the need to make it to be <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: @guiverc It's not addressing my questions

Comment: If I hit ^N to open a new browser window, it'll open & become my active window. If I hit ALT+F4 it'll close the window I just opened and return me to the window I'm on now.  As is highlighted in that linked question "*It depends upon the application whether to respond to this event closing all together the application, or iconize*"; it is up to the program you are using currently how they interpret the ALT+F4, ie. it'll depend on unspecified programs you are using.  I tried four programs on my system, it worked on all four I tried.

Answer (score 3):

CTRL + Q it seems,
Though still don't know how to map it to be ALT + F4

Comment: Asking how to map keystrokes to a command has been answered before. Try the Search box at the top of the page.